# SQL query to select row from one table which is not in another table

Tags: mysql, join

**Registraion** and **group_members**

```
Registration Table
id  name  
-------                
1   A    
2   B    
3   C
4   D

group_members Table
name  Gid 
-------                
A   01    
B   01    
C   02
```

I need to get the names from **registration** table which are not a member in **group_members** table with **Gid is 02**.
The output must be obviously **A,B and D**.
But I dont know how to achieve this.Please help.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Registration AS t1
LEFT JOIN Group_members AS t2 ON t1.name = t2.name AND t2.Gid = '02'
WHERE t2.name IS NULL
```

This will filter out any matching records in `group_members` table with `Gid = '02'`.

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
select name from
Registration reg where 
not exists 
(select null 
from group_members gm
where gm.name = reg.name
and gm.gid = '02')
```